# Power Automate API Call with OAuth 2.0 Token

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

I would like to access an API using Power Automate. The API requires authorisation using OAuth 2.0 and each API call must include an Authorization header including a valid Bearer Access Token. The access token is valid for 7 days.

Currently, to do this I have:

1. Retrieved the API Secret using "GET SECRET" action and connected it to Azure Vault
2. Use a HTTP action to get the token
3. Parse the Token Response
4. Added another HTTP action but this time using the access_token value as the Authorization Bearer

This works but is this the correct way to do this? The access token is valid for 7 days but my flow will call a new one each time it is ran. Should I be storing the access token securely somehow so it can be reused? Should I be using a custom connector?

**Example access token response:**

```
[
    {
        "token_type": "bearer",
        "access_token": "C8A1P9FiVsMlNN_fGa1Y59jquV5kSNqsHG",
        "expires_in": 604799,
        ".issued": "Wed, 18 Oct 2021 15:59:14 GMT",
        ".expires": "Wed, 25 Oct 2021 15:59:14 GMT"
    }
]
```

**My flow:**

[image]

Thanks, Greg

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your requirements.

If you, for example, have to pay for each access token and you call this authorization endpoint many times per day, maybe you should create two flows.

1. The first flow runs weekly, creating a new token and storing it in your keyvault.
2. Your second flow is your user- or system-triggered flow, which only takes the token from the keyvault and does your actions.

As said, it all depends on your licenses, preferred way of working, requirements, you name it.

If all these options are not applicable, just leave your flow as is. :)