# Power Automate + Azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, power-automate

I am currently looking at updating a users AD Property "Employee Hire Date" using a Power Automate flow.

I have gotten all of the users details, but whenever I try to update the users "EmployeeHireDate" it just gives me the following error:

```
"error": {
"code": "Request_BadRequest",
"message": "Invalid value specified for property 'employeeHireDate' of resource 'User'.",
"details": [
  {
    "code": "InvalidValue",
    "message": "Invalid value specified for property 'employeeHireDate' of resource 'User'.",
    "target": "employeeHireDate"
  }
```

I have tried to following values:

```
dd-MM-yyyy

MM-dd-yyyy

yyyy-MM-dd

yyyy-dd-MM

2021-02-03T08:00:00Z
```

However, it keeps throwing the same error. I have asked in the Power Automate fourms but haven't had much of a reply.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried to check the issue using microsoft graph api:

First I fetched and checked the correct date time format for the user to update later  with

- Authorize endpoint:  `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/authorize`
- Token endpoint: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantid/oauth2/v2.0/token`

**Scope:** `email openid profile` or  `https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read https://graph.microsoft.com/User.ReadWrite.All` or  `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`

I gave scope: `https://grpah.microsoft.com/.default`  to include all microsoft graph api permissions.

We obtain access token form token endpoint having correct permissions:

Then put
Headers:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: Bearer {accessToken}
```

Replace {accessToken} with an access token that has the necessary permissions to update user properties in Azure AD.

Obtain an access token using the "HTTP" action and the Azure AD OAuth 2.0 authentication flow.

see [power-automate-api-call-with-oauth-2-0-token | Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69978061/power-automate-api-call-with-oauth-2-0-token)

---

**GET**
**`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/uxxo@mxxx.onmicrosoft.com?$select=employeeHireDate`**

---

Response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#users(employeeHireDate)/$entity",
    "employeeHireDate": "2023-03-27T18:30:00Z"
}
```

[image]

Then tried to update employee hire date:

---

**PATCH**  `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/usertwo@m3xxx9.onmicrosoft.com?$select=employeeHireDate`

---

**Note:** Make sure the value is given in string format i.e; in double quotes

1st way

Body:

```
{
    
    "employeeHireDate": "2023-03-24T18:30:00Z"
}
```

*2nd way*

Body:
{

```
    "employeeHireDate": "2023-03-23"
}
```

Both of the above worked and are reflected when GET request is made:

[image]

[image]

Portal view of users properties is updated:

[image]

Update did not work with follwoing

```
{
    
    "employeeHireDate": "2023-22-03"
}
```

When the value is given wrong, here I gave **date** **32** which doesn’t exist .

```
{
    "employeeHireDate": "2023-03-32"
}
```

I got the error:

```
 "error": {
        "code": "Request_BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid datetime value: 2023-03-32",
}
```

[image]

So kindly check ***the Date is valid*** or not and the ***proper permissions*** to update the user are present to your application and granted admin consent before running the power automate:

One of the following application and delegated permissions are required:

```
User.ManageIdentities.All, User.EnableDisableAccount.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All
```

[image]

> **Note:** The following properties cannot be updated by an app with only application permissions: aboutMe, birthday, employeeHireDate,
> interests, mySite, pastProjects, responsibilities, schools, and
> skills.

[Update user - Microsoft Graph v1.0 | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)